# The delete http request for microposts in Figure 13.54 of Michael Hartl's tutorial has no route matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

From the [following excerpt](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#code-micropost_user_mismatch_test) of the section:

```
test "should redirect destroy for wrong micropost" do
  log_in_as(users(:michael))
  micropost = microposts(:ants)
  assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
    delete micropost_path(micropost)
  end
  assert_redirected_to root_url
end
```

the following line

```
delete micropost_path(micropost)
```

was giving me the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches 
{:action=>"/microposts/583546149", :controller=>"microposts"}
```

Comparing the action: portion to snippets I had seen online of typical delete http requests clued me in that something was inherently wrong. I had curiously noted, too, that in the tutorial Michael Hartl normally used the following syntax for deleting resources:

```
delete :destroy, id: micropost
```

Just to be clear, the latter seems to work as expected. My question, then, is twofold:

Are both supposed to be valid? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

That test is to make sure that micropost(:ants) cannot be created because the method is micropost(:oranges). that is why it gave an error and redirected, which is what it was supposed to do. so the test passed.

Test syntax may differ.